# SQL - Updating two columns where one is dependent on other

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I want to update two columns of a table at a time where Column B is dependent on Column A.

**Before update**

```
ColA ColB

A11  NULL

B22  NULL

C33  NULL

D44  NULL
```

**After update**

```
ColA ColB

11  A

22  B

33  C

44  D
```

I am writning the update statement as

```
UPDATE tbl SET ColA = STUFF(ColA,1,1,''), ColB = LEFT(ColA, 1)
```

Here ColB should be updated before ColA which is working fine for small result set. But, how will it behave when there are large number of records? Does the SQL update happen randomly?

I am really not sure if it will update ColA only when ColB update is finished. This can be achieved by CTE, but I want to know how the update really works here.

Comment: you should probably write a function or a trigger for this

Comment: I have the query with me which works perfectly ie.  using CTE. I want to know is there any chance where ColA will be updated before ColB for a row?

Answer (score 1):

There will not be an issue at all.  SQL is declarative and will make your statement work somehow.

For laughs (or confidence building) try `SET a=b, b=a`

It will swap the values though to a procedural mindset it should not.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN
Create Table #Temp (ColA NVARCHAR(10),ColB NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 'A11',  NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B22',  NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C33',  NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D44' , NULL


SELECT * FROM #Temp
UPDATE #Temp SET ColA=SUBSTRING(ColA,2,2),ColB=SUBSTRING(ColA,1,1)

SELECT * FROM #Temp
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This can be achieved using CTE as well. My concern is single update statement which I stated above. Will there be any issue with that?

Comment: NO There won't be Any Issue If you are Not Sure Take The Changes in Temp Table And Check it.If everything seems proper you can take changes in User_Table too..